# Selenium Webdriver - No alert is present Error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String alertText = "";
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
        driver.get("https://gogiftz.com/default/");

        WebElement contact = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='root-wrapper']/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a"));
        contact.click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='telephone']")).sendKeys("04364249425");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='comment']")).sendKeys("aasdfghlkjhjghkj");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='name']")).sendKeys("abcdef");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("abcdef@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='contactForm']/div[2]/button")).submit();

        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alertText = alert.getText();
        System.out.println(alertText);
        alert.accept();
    }
}
```

I was trying to find alert present in the WebDriver using above code. But I am getting this type of error in below.

> No alert is present (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Help me to fix this Error...

Comment: Is alert is displaying on navigating manually? so time popup will display but it may not be javascript popup. its simple web page only you can find elements for that popup. please check once

Comment: There is no alert shown even manually. Can you check that again.

Answer (score 0):

below mentioned issue may be causing this exception

1. Alert is not present on page, which i guess you already have checked. If not then revisit the code and perform the action that triggers the alert.
2. Otherwise, It's because of synchronization issue. What it means is that as soon as page load is done the alert is not present on page and it might be appearing after a while so you can give it a try by putting wait statement.

   driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for alert to be present before You interact with it.

It work better in older drivers, new require it.

So first wait for alert to be present, then interact with it.